# pyqgis splitGeometry practical working example

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to get splitGeometry working example in qgis where i can find it. Official documentation have define [here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html) but this is not enough. Where i can get its working example in order to understand it and use in my project.

Answer (score 2):

By using Official Documentation for 'splitGeometry' of **QgsGeometry** and shapefiles at next image:

[image]

I tried out my own code based in Maplus link:

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

feat_1 = layers[0].getFeatures().next()

feat_2 = layers[1].getFeatures().next()

if feat_1.geometry().intersects(feat_2.geometry()):
    success, splits, topo = feat_1.geometry().splitGeometry(feat_2.geometry().asPolygon()[0], True)

    if success == 0:

        print splits[0].exportToWkt()

        geom = QgsGeometry()

        print geom.fromPolyline(topo).exportToWkt()
```

First argument of 'splitGeometry' is a **QgsPoint** list, 'splits' is a geometry list and 'topo' is also a **QgsPoint** list. Results printed at Python Console of QGIS were:

[image]

So, I used **QuickWKT** plugin for visualizing these results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try GitHub search. Here is link: [GitHub splitGeometry search](https://github.com/search?l=python&q=splitgeometry&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

For some reason link is not working. Please just visit github page and write splitGeometry. Then click on Code on the left panel and choose python. There are 25 examples.

There are some examples how people use this method in python. It is very good way how to get info about using other methods in pyqgis because of small numbers of pyqgis examples.

Here are specific project using this method: [Mapplus](https://github.com/mapplus/qgis-processing/blob/4ce39735e6275636937530a4ee199a2b3b470e56/processing/algs/qgis/SplitLinesWithLines.py)

```
geom_b = QgsGeometry(feat_b.geometry())
        if geom_b.intersects(geom_a):
            success, splits, topo = geom_a.splitGeometry(geom_b.asPolyline(), True) # split polygon by line
            if success == 0:
                     #if it success you can make other operations
```

Comment: what is this nothing found

Comment: it should working now, sry for that. Is this OK now? I don't know why link didn't work.

Comment: If you have still problem with searching, just click on search again. It is working. There is 25 matches.

Comment: We could not perform this search

Comment: You probably need account on github, did you try Mapplus link?